# SDK for Nintendo's wii

Tags: nintendo, wiiuse

can any one tell me from where i can download nintendo's wii sdk. I am not able to find it anywhere. Also can I get this SDK for free, or can I just get SDK doc?

Comment: Have you tried a basic Google search on the subject?

Comment: Yes I have tried. But its SDK is not free as far as I know, or we have to be official developer for Nintendo.

Answer (score 4):

Kindly refer the Authorized Nintendo Developers and Publishers - **Wario World**

http://warioworld.com/apply/

or join this discussion on GameDev.SE

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14728/how-does-one-obtain-an-official-nintendo-development-sdk